# Html helper does not use custom VirtualPathProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have set up a `VirtualPathProvider` and it is working fine for direct url calls like `http://.../home/index` in the address bar.

```
public class HomeController
{   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // This triggers MyVirtualPathProvider functionallity when called via
        // the browsers address bar or anchor tag click for that matter.
        // But it does not trigger MyVirtualPathProvider for 'in-view' calls like
        // @{ Html.RenderAction("index", "home"); }
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{

    public override System.Web.Hosting.VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        // This method gets hit after the Controller call for return View(...);
        if (MyCondition)
            return MyVirtualFileHandler.Get(virtualPath);
        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        // This method gets hit after the Controller call for return View(...);
        if (MyCondition)
            return true;
        return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }

}
```

However, I would like this to work for the Html helper too, but right now it is ignoring the `VirtualPathProvider` for the html helper calls in the view:

```
@{
     Html.RenderAction("index", "home");
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

In addtion I have an override for the WebViewPage so I would be able to override the initialization for helpers, but I haven't got a clue with what or how.

**Edit:**

I have tried this at two computers and, oddly enough, it works on another computer.
So the question would actually become:

Why does the VirtualPathProvider works on one and fails for 50% on another computer?
But then this question would then become somewhat to vague, speculative even.
Nonetheless I am not happy with this but it seems I would have to reinstall some things. :(

Comment: What do you mean? The child view does go to the custom `VirtualPathProvider` in my test. Here is my [test project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14576915/VirtualPath.zip). If you look at the Output tab in VS, you should see `GetFile /Views/Home/Child.cshtml` being logged on the first request

Comment: @LostInComputer Your project works indeed, I am going to determine whether my projects uses different assemblies. It could also be a package difference. Otherwise my project might be messed up. With me it just doesn't work for Html.RenderAction. I will look into it. Thanks for your example project.

Comment: Maybe the file has already been cached so `GetFile` and `FileExist` doesn't get called for that file anymore

Comment: @LostInComputer That should not be the case, because I have tried to prevent it in multiple ways. Clearing cache manually by killing the webserver process and deleting the temporary ASP.NET files, renaming the action.

Comment: @LostInComputer I have tried your solution at the computer I initially had the problem on and oddly enough it fails at that specific computer when it comes to `RenderAction()` and all other html helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User LostInComputer was kind enough to hand over a sample project which worked on my notebook and I was confused about what would be the difference.

Normally one would expect indeed that Html helpers would *just* work for the `VirtualPathProvider`, and now I know it should.

The actual problem lies within the installation of the particular pc where I encountered the problem on and after a reinstall everything worked just fine.
So it is not really a sophisticated solution, but since there has been little attention to this question I am at least giving it my own answer, because this could be useful stuff to someone else some day, how dull it might be. :)

**When you would surely expect something to work, you could always try to run it on a different machine (if you have one available of course), because in the end all that could be wrong might just be a corrupt installation.** :(